# Regex tom match percentage upto 2 decimal places

Tags: regex, validation

I need regular expression for percentage which satisfy following conditions.

1. numbers between 0.1 to 100.
2. Maximum up to 2 decimal place.It can accept up to one decimal place also like 0.1.
3. Accept numbers up to 100 without decimal like 1,2,3----100.
4. Can accept decimal without stating with 0 , like .11,.1,.2 ..

I am using following regex , but its not working properly.

```
^(100\.00|[1-9]?\d\.\d{2})$
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely, one of these will help you: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=percent&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use this regex:

```
^((?:|0|[1-9]\d?|100)(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

[image]

**[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/lT5tJ2/3)**

Comment: You're welcome. I just slightly edited my answer to include `100.00`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Regex, made a few modifications to the one you made so that you can understand it better.

```
^(100(\.0{1,2})?|[0-9]{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is simplified and works.

`^(100|\d{0,2})(\.\d{1,2})?$`