# Is there a cleaner Regex expression for what I have in mind?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to only accept input as numerical values `0 to 100`, `integers` and `floats` with **max** `two` decimal places inclusive, and write a regular expression to check these conditions.

For example, I want it to accept values such as:

```
0(min), 0.1, 1, 11, 11.1, 11.11, 100(max).
```

But not any of:

```
-1, 100.1, 111, 1+1, .1, etc.
```

So far I came up with `^\d?\d+(\.\d\d?)?$` except that it has a bunch of problems.

Just now while submitting this, I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800074/regex-tom-match-percentage-upto-2-decimal-places) in similar questions sidebar that has what seems to be the solution ( `"^((?:|0|[1-9]\d?|100)(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$"` ), except that it also accepts `100.01` to `100.99`. Other than that, which is a very minor issue, it should work.

But does anybody know how to patch that particular bit?

Comment: How are you getting this input from the user? via command line or some kind o ui?

Comment: using python input()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`100` is the only real exception here, so it should be fairly simple:

`^(?:100|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$`

https://regex101.com/r/Rr0gs4/1

Edit: to also allow `100.0` and `100.00`:

`^(?:100(?:\.00?)?|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$`

Comment: Not sure if it is a requirement. But this matches 01 or 02.22

Comment: Probably it's not desirable to match `01`. You can fix that by changing `\d{1,2}` to `[1-9]?\d`

Comment: To prevent the problem of the leading 0, you can add `(?!0\d)` before `\d{1,2}`. Or you can change `\d{1,2}` (the first) to `[1-9]?\d`

Comment: Good point, although I'm not sure if the OP actually wants to exclude those patterns. I'll edit the answer if we get confirmation.

Comment: It's fine even if 00.01-09.99 are accepted as values with a leading zero. However just a slight problem with this is that it doesn't allow for 100.00. Is there a way to be inclusive of 100.00 but not 100.01-100.99?

Comment: I've added a minor alteration to this in order to accept 100.00.
`^(?:100(\.00?)?|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$` works for my purposes. As this is the most similar, I've accepted this as the answer :)

Comment: Edited the answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you get the input, it may be easier and quicker to simply check the numerical value.

```
def acceptable(str_val):
    try:
        return 0 <= float(str_val) <= 100
    except ValueError:
        return False

acceptable('1.11')
# True

acceptable('abc')
# False

acceptable('100.0')
# True

acceptable('100.1')
# False
```

Comment: +1 I agree, although this is not exactly what the OP wanted, I think its clearer and/or more Pythonic...

Comment: +1, interesting solution to my issue and as Joe says, this would be clearer and more Pythonic. If I had not limited my question to purely regex expressions, and if I could accept multiple answers, I totally would this as well. This is really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This tests all the allowable inputs and the example non-allowable inputs.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^(100(\.00?)?|((\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d\d?)?))$')

def matches(s):
    print('Testing', s)
    return bool(regex.search(s))

for i in range(0, 101):
    s = str(i)
    assert matches(s), 'no match for %s' % s

for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        s = '{i}.{j}'.format(i=i, j=j)
        assert matches(s), 'no match for %s' % s

        # Special case for .0N (e.g., 1.01, 1.02, etc)
        if j == 0:
            for k in range(0, 10):
                s = '{i}.0{k}'.format(i=i, k=k)
                assert matches(s), 'no match for %s' % s

non_matches = ('-1', '100.1', '111', '1+1', '.1', 'abc')
for s in non_matches:
    assert not matches(s), 'unexpected match for %s' % s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `re.match(r'(\d{,2}\.?\d*)?|(100)?', 'string_goes_here')`